# Compare catch message from exception

Tags: java, exception

Help. I build a new class (ParseException) that extends the `RuntimeException`.
In another class I check for invalid String (only letters and numbers),
if it's invalid it throw a ParseException with message of the invalid token.
Now I wanna test if the throw massage is according to the invalid token. 
So I wonder how can I get to the `message` that was thrown from the Exception.
So I am trying

```
catch (ParseException ex) { 
        test(ParseException.equal( "For input string: "#""),"should be ParseException ");
}
```

and

```
catch (ParseException ex) { 
        test(massage.equal( "For input string: "#""),"should be ParseException ");
}
```

and other wrong things. Still it's wrong and I don't know how to get to the message field that catch.

Comment: Isn't it just `ex.massage`?

Comment: `ex.getMessage()` should return the detail message string

Comment: yep it it's . thnkas!!

Comment: I don't know if I wold be comfortable getting a massage from an Exception... I hear they can be pretty rough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to extract information programmatically from exception messages. Instead create a new exception class that has an attribute that holds the value of interest.